# Writing function returning componnent of vector

Tags: r

I want to write a function that, given a list L, each of whose components is a vector,returns an integer vector V, such that for each i, V[i] is the length of L[[i]]

Comment: lapply(name.of.list,length())

Comment: @Lekh: The two reasons that didn't work are that a) `lapply` returns a list, not a vector, and b) you need to give it the function `length` by itself, not `length()`, which is trying to call the function with no arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sapply:

```
sapply(L, length)
```

For example:

```
L = list(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 3), c(3, 4, 5, 6))
sapply(L, length)
# [1] 3 2 4
```

Comment: Thanks! David, However I was looking for the function that will work for any length integer vector.

Comment: That will work with any length vectors inside the list...

Comment: @Lekh: I don't understand your comment. This would work for any length of either the list or the individual vectors.

Comment: @DavidRobinson just wanted to write similar to sapply function myself....

Comment: @Lekh: `sapply` is both the easiest and the computationally fastest solution. Why do you want to write something else yourself?

Comment: `myFun <- function(aList) sapply(aList, length)`

Comment: ML<-function(L) {
   t<-length(L) #t is the length of the list L
   R<-numeric()  
   for(i in 1:t) R[i]<-length(L[[i]])
   R  
}

Comment: @Lekh: that does the same thing as `sapply` but takes several times as much code and runs considerably slower (especially on large lists). Why do you want to do that?